# forloop not working as expected in a batch file but works if it is given in a commandprompt

Tags: batch-file

```
for %a in ("%ProjectName: =" "%") do (@CALL c:\SikuliX\runScript.cmd -r  C:\LoadTesting\Moderator\%~a_Moderator\src\%~a_Moderator.sikuli)
```

The above statement works fine, if it is given in a commandprompt but fails if it is inside a batch file, and the error I get while running this batch file is :

```
 C:\>testBatch.bat
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~a_Student\src\%~a_Student.sikuli)

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
testBatch.bat was unexpected at this time.

C:\>for SikuliProjectName: =" "\SikuliX\runScript.cmd -r C:\LoadTesting\Student\
r C:\LoadTesting\Student\%~a_Student\src\%~a_Student.sikuli)
```

Please provide any solution to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just follow the instructions "For valid formats type ... FOR /?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double the `%` to `%%` in the for loop metavariables.

Comment: Changed it to : for %%a in ("%SikuliProjectName: =" "%") do (@CALL c:\SikuliX\runScript.cmd -r C:\LoadTesting\Moderator\%%~a_Moderator\src\%%~a_Moderator.sikuli)